# ¿How make the correct animation? (Android java without xml)

Tags: java, android, animation, animator

I have the next code:

```
public void desaparecer(final LinearLayout parent, View hijo, int espaciofinal) {

        parent.removeView(hijo); //remote the view of the parent

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)parent.getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams(); //create the params

        final int espacioIni = parent.getChildAt(0).getHeight(); //i get the height from start

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params.height, espaciofinal); //pass the params and the final height

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

                params.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                parent.getChildAt(0).requestLayout(); //request
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(300); //set the anim duration   

        animator.start(); //start the animation

    }
```

The animation don't work well. The idea would be that start the animation with the initial height. (This would be the correct way)

But, by reasons that i don't understand, the height (when start the animation) pass to be 0 and i need that don't destroy the original height.

Any idea? I accept all ideas, except xml sources. I can't use it by reasons of my team.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For animation of changes on a layout you can set animateLayoutChanges="true" to ViewGroup item. And any changes will be animated with default animation. If you want to change the animation behavior you can set to ViewGroup your oun LayoutTransition object. Here [google talks video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g) which can help you, I hope )

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
final int espacioIni = parent.getChildAt(2).getHeight();

    params.height = espacioIni;

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params.height,espacio);
```

into ofInt pass the correct parametres and work well (startParameter, finishParameter)